# Could not replicate Plotly Express Python graph in Plotly JS

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, plotly.js

I want to replicate the entire graph shown in the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

It is made using Plotly Express Python Scatter Plot, however I need to plot the entire graph using PlotlyJs. I have tried to pass the same properties in the JS scatter Plot but I am not able to get the desired result. I have tried searching the PlotlyJS documentation but was unsuccessful. I passed the same properties color, size, symbol like I passed in the Px.scatter but it didn't worked.

Please help me by sending a reference or so so that I can replicate it in JS.

**Edit:**

I am pasting the entire code below.

**Python Code (which I want to replicate in PlotlyJS**

```
fig = px.scatter(x=x, y=y, color=color, symbol = symbol,
            title = 'Patient Health Plot', 
             labels = {'color':'Patient', 'symbol':'Time','size':'Severity', '0':labels['0'], '1':labels['1']}, 
             size = size)
  fig.show()
```

*The values passed here x,y,color,symbol are `NUMPY ARRAYS` sectioned from a `Pandas Dataframe`. I have built an API which sends this data as json which can be imported in the React Plotly-JS app*

**For the code below, I have manually added the values just for testing purposes**

**PlotlyJS Code (inside a React App)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './page.css'
import Plotly from "plotly.js-basic-dist";
import createPlotlyComponent from "react-plotly.js/factory";
const Plot = createPlotlyComponent(Plotly);

export default class PCA extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='PCA'>
        PCA
        <Plot
          data={[
            {
              x: [-5.691238139127018,
                16.02561825924827,
              -19.482347122543963,
                22.79664620239432,
                9.27281358669174,
              -19.89458153037701,
              -2.1475704679740293,
                0.8395889051651714,
              -5.162839175882285,
              -1.8356646308243358,
              -13.854581667215033,
                6.155185565188921,
                14.41696750169902,
              -12.413456433571344,
                17.97832792203258,
              -7.002868774905083],
              y: [0.078247758751456,
                4.471210394686129,
                16.496418817153604,
                7.088318145789984,
                -2.501368997923566,
                -4.159977694060695,
                -7.335497257865577,
                4.605541034829036,
                -9.85701386098633,
                7.174241441255795,
                -10.40241299755566,
                -10.76765189142554,
                11.382045078953835,
                -17.98191393628625,
                -9.722118669880018],
              type: 'scatter',
              mode: 'markers',
              marker: {
              
                symbol: ["S","S","S","S","S","S","S","S","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E"],
                size:["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "27", "33", "15", "50", "25", "27", "1", "33"],
                color: ["1","2","3","4","6","11","12","14","1","2","3","4","6","11","12","14"]
 

         },
        }
      ]}
      layout={{ width: 500, height: 500, title: 'Patient Health Plot' }}
    />
  </div>
)
```

}
}

The output of PlotlyJS:

[image: plotlyjs screenshot]

Comment: Can you please attach the Plotly.js code you have written so far as formatted text? That way we can see what you have tried and help you out with a more specific problem

Comment: Hi @DerekO, I have modified the question and provided the entire code, please check now, thanks.