# Is there any way to display Plotly Express Graph in React App

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, plotly.js, plotly-express

Plotly Express provides very easy functions to draw customizable scatter plots, since I did not get any help regarding this question from over a week -> [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67606456/could-not-replicate-plotly-express-python-graph-in-plotly-js), I even tried to get help on Plotly Community Forum but no success there also.

So I am not able to *replicate* the exact scatterplot made in Plotly Express Python in PlotlyJS.

Is there any way to directly embed Plotly Express graphs in React Application?

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: did you find a way to fix it? see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72930513/how-to-plot-plotly-chart-on-react-from-json-response-from-flask-api?rq=3

Answer (score 0):

you can use histogram
`data[index] = { "x": [], type: 'histogram'};`